# tooltip displays black block before displaying actual values in IE 10

Tags: d3.js

The tooltip in this fiddle works all fine in chrome, but it displays black block before displaying the actual value in IE10.

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/11/)

Here is the code i have used to create tooltip

```
   .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
        .style('opacity', 1.0)
        .style('background', 'white')
        .style('display','block')


    tooltip.html( d.global )
        .style('left',(d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
})
.on('mouseout', function(d) {
    tooltip.transition()
        .style('opacity', 1)
        .style('display','none')
})
```

this is the style i have used for tooltip

```
 .hor_tooltip {
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: auto;
padding: 10px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
pointer-events: none;
display:none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed

```
.style('background', 'white')
```

from tooltip.transition since 'background-color' attribute was always present in tooltip class; it works fine now.